# app crashed on scrolling images left in slide show

Tags: android

App crashed on scrolling image from left to right in slideshow
These are the logcat errors

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams
    at android.widget.Gallery.setUpChild(Gallery.java:902)
    at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:881)
    at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryLeftLtr(Gallery.java:760)
    at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryLeft(Gallery.java:705)
    at android.widget.Gallery.trackMotionScroll(Gallery.java:401)
    at android.widget.Gallery$FlingRunnable.run(Gallery.java:1538)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5185)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Wrong type casting. Please post relevant code block.

Comment: MenuItem mediaRouteItem = menu.findItem( R.id.menuChromecast );
    android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton = (android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton) mediaRouteItem.getActionView();
 // MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) mediaRouteItem.getActionView();
  System.out.println("MediaRouteButton"+mediaRouteButton);
//      chromecastAddIn = new ChromecastAddin();
//      chromecastAddIn.onCreate(this, mediaRouteButton);